# Random class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I've very new to C++ and have been working through a tutorial and got as far as `std::rand()`. I was immediately horrified and rushed out to see if I could implement this as a service. This is my (pretty basic) non-cryptographically-secure implementation in the style of .Net's [`System.Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There are a number of things I'm unhappy about:

- **Anemic object.** TBH there isn't much implementation here. Am I just (wrongly) trying to crowbar c++ into my .Net way of thinking? Is it a redundant layer of abstraction on top of the more powerful `<random>` library. However, my goal is to pass around one service for random numbers (to absolutely avoid hard coding things dependencies from `<random>` in my classes) and I'm not sure this can be achieved using `<random>` directly.
- **Lifetime of the distributions**. I'm not really sure what this should be. I've gone for the lifetime of the Random object where possible, but in the methods where I take a max-min value for each call this has not been possible. I'm pretty sure `std::mt19937` should have the same lifetime as my `Random` object.
- **Hard-coded uniform distributions**. Preferably I would like some kind of IOC, it would be nice to pass in whether I'm using a uniform, poisson etc. I've looked inside the class and there a lot of templates, could I somehow wrap this into factory class that has methods to return int-returning-distributions, double-returning-distributions etc (would that even be a good idea?)? Given that System.Random has a hardcoded unif dist, arguably this may to too much IOC.

[I think I've found an implementation that uses templates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71313/generate-a-random-numbers-class) but I'm not really sure it's solving the IOC problem.

**Interface: IRandom.h** (Has no corresponding .cpp file)

```
#pragma once
class IRandom
{
public: 
    virtual int32_t Next() = 0;
    virtual int32_t Next(int32_t maxValue) = 0;
    virtual int32_t Next(int32_t minValue, int32_t maxValue) = 0;
    virtual double_t NextDouble() = 0;
    virtual double_t NextDouble(double_t minValue, double_t maxValue) = 0;
    virtual void NextBytes(std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer) = 0;
};
```

**Random.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <random>
#include "IRandom.h"
class Random : public IRandom
{
    std::mt19937 _randomNumberGenerator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double_t> _realDistribution;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int32_t> _bytedistribution;
public:
    Random(uint_least32_t seed);
    Random() : Random(std::_Random_device()) {};
    ~Random();
    int32_t Next();
    int32_t Next(int32_t maxValue);
    int32_t Next(int32_t minValue, int32_t maxValue);
    double_t NextDouble();
    double_t NextDouble(double_t minValue, double_t maxValue);
    void NextBytes(std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer);
};
```

**Random.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Random.h"
#include <random>

Random::Random(uint_least32_t seed)
{
    this->_randomNumberGenerator = std::mt19937(seed);
    this->_realDistribution = std::uniform_real_distribution<double_t>();
    this->_bytedistribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<int32_t>(0, 256);
}

int32_t Random::Next()
{
    return this->Next(0, INT32_MAX);
}

int32_t Random::Next(int32_t maxValue)
{
    return this->Next(0, maxValue);
}

int32_t Random::Next(int32_t minValue, int32_t maxValue)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int32_t> distribution(minValue, maxValue);
    return distribution(this->_randomNumberGenerator);
}

double_t Random::NextDouble()
{
    return this->_realDistribution(this->_randomNumberGenerator);
}

double_t Random::NextDouble(double_t minValue, double_t maxValue)
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double_t> distribution(minValue, minValue);
    return this->_realDistribution(this->_randomNumberGenerator);
}

void Random::NextBytes(std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer)
{   
    for (auto &i : buffer)
    {
        i = static_cast<uint8_t>(_bytedistribution(this->_randomNumberGenerator));
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
unique_ptr<IRandom> randomService = make_unique<Random>();

cout << "NUMBERS" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << randomService->Next(0,10) << endl;
}

auto buffer = vector<uint8_t>(100);
randomService->NextBytes(buffer);

cout << "BUFFER" << endl;
for (auto &i : buffer)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: Related [video](http://video.ch9.ms/ch9/9fb9/5f4cd3b3-4569-4651-987a-46dcc2739fb9/GN13STLrandConsideredHarmful.wmv) and [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/best-way-to-generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library). Right that end of the video it seems to be confirmed that creating distributions very often isn't a problem, but it also is suggested that the range can be modified on an existing distribution (I looked and max and min are modifiable), but this mutability seems to go against the intent of the object.

Comment: I wrote similar code before the new standard introduced the `<random>` library. [The "engine" selection was template based](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63317/small-pre-c11-pseudo-random-library?rq=1). Being honest with you, I don't see much use for this today besides enforcing your own C#-ish style, though there might be some legitimate cases where you might need to select the random engine at runtime. That would be the only justification for the abstract interface, IMHO.

Comment: BTW, if you are still interested about `rand()` and the new C++ libraries, I think this article might be of interest: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Comment: @glampert Interesting article. It may not have been immediately obvious, but my problem with it is that I do want to enforce my own c#-ish style. Specifically I don't see the advantages of dependency injection as something I need to check at the door when entering a new language.

Comment: I don't see why you need an interface class here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some comments mostly related to coding style and overall C++ practices (roughly in order of appearance):

1. Your interface is missing a [`virtual` destructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-dtors.html). This is an important thing for an abstract interface and your code is actually invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when trying to destroy an instance of `IRandom` without one. With C++11, the proper way of declaring a virtual destructor in a pure interface class is using the `= default` destructor idion:

   ```
   virtual ~IRandom() = default;
   ```
2. Using `double_t` is very unusual, since `double` is normally the same but with less typing. Unless you really have a good reason for `double_t`, you should stick to the native `double` instead. I would say the same about using `int32_t`. Unless you really care about using strictly sized 32bit integers, just go for a plain ol' `int`.
3. By the way, when using the sized types, like `int32_t` and friends, from [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint), make sure to include the header file. You are relying on a residual include probably from `<random>`, which might not be there on other compilers or even on a future version of your current one. At any rate, it is also good practice making dependencies clear.
4. When using the types from `<cstdint>`, the correct way of referencing its members is thru the `std::` namespace. They happen to also visible at the global level because on most compilers `stdint.h` (the C header) and `cstdint` (the C++ header) are implemented as wrappers to the same file. There is no requirement from the C++ Standard that this be implemented is such way, so a C++ compiler is not required to provide `int32_t` and friends outside the `std` namespace when including `cstdint`.
5. [`std::numeric_limits<T>::[min][max]()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is preferred over the `INT*_MAX / INT*_MIN` macros.
6. Prefixing in-class member access with `this->` is very rare in C++. You should only be doing that when, for instance, you need to disambiguate some shadowed member access (but even that is discouraged because shadowing members is a bit of a design flaw; better to uniquely name your variables and methods).
7. Identifiers beginning with underscore carry a few restrictions in C++ ([Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654)). Your use inside a class for member variables is not wrong, but might be frowned upon. Consider perhaps other styles, such as the `m_prefix` or and underscore `atTheEnd_`. Or no distinction at all for member variables.
8. I think you probably meant to camelCase `_bytedistribution` but mistyped the `d` in "distribution".
9. This is not the ideal way of initializing data in a constructor:

   > ```
   > Random::Random(uint_least32_t seed)
   > {
   >     this->_randomNumberGenerator = std::mt19937(seed);
   >     this->_realDistribution = std::uniform_real_distribution<double_t>();
   >     this->_bytedistribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<int32_t>(0, 256);
   > }
   > ```

   That way you are calling the implicit default constructor and then reinitializing the members with the assignment operator. That's an easy mistake to make when both Java and C# use that syntax, but the proper way of initializing in a C++ constructor is by calling the constructor of the member object:

   ```
   Random::Random(uint_least32_t seed)
       : _randomNumberGenerator(seed)
       , _realDistribution() // <-- This one takes no arguments, so this line could even be omitted.
       , _byteDistribution(0, 256)
   { }
   ```

   Notice that it is a list of comma separated constructor calls, with the first starting at the `:`. This is called the [*constructor initialization list*](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). C++11 also allows replacing the `( )` in the constructor calls by `{ }`, so `_randomNumberGenerator{ seed }` would also be valid, if you happen to prefer that syntax.
10. While the virtual destructor in the interface definition is necessary, in your implementation class it is not. There is no reason for declaring an empty destructor but to making it a default virtual one. So you can just erase the destructor of `Random` if no manual cleanup is needed.
11. <strike>`#include "stdafx.h"` is very Visual Studio specific and I personally dislike it since it makes your code non-portable for free. If you could get rid of it, I don't see why you shouldn't (usually involves just deleting that line and adjusting a setting on the IDE to disable precompiled headers).</strike> **Edit:** This point aroused some discussion in the comments section, so let me start over. I'm not advocating against the use of precompiled headers, they can have their value on large projects. My problem with `stdafx.h` in this particular case and other small projects is that it is going to be the only thing that prevents the code from compiling elsewhere (say with GCC or Clang). If I copy-paste this, as it stands, into a couple files, I'll have to either remove that line or create an empty `stdafx.h` before I can build it, which is a nuisance, when the code could be ready to compile on other systems without any change if wasn't for this. Of course that if we are not talking about a code snippet in a website, but a source code tree distributed as a project, with a proper build system, this do not apply, since the build system should be properly configured to handle precompiled headers.
12. Add the new [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier to methods of your implementation class (`Random`). This feature is meant to aid compiler diagnostics and provide better warning/error messages, as well as clearly communicating your intentions to human readers.
13. Regarding you tiny usage example, statically allocated object instances are usually not declared like this:

    > ```
    > auto buffer = vector<uint8_t>(100);
    > ```

    But instead using this syntax:

    ```
    vector<uint8_t> buffer(100); 
    //  ^            ^      ^--- (optional) constructor call
    //  +--- type    |
    //               +--- variable
    ```

    **Note:** Herb Sutter [seems to disagree](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/) (thanks [@ChrisDrew](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41428/chris-drew) for the comment). Personally, I am down for `auto` and type inference whenever it makes code shorter or easier to read. In this particular case, it is just more typing (which defeats one of the purposes of type inference, BTW). The constructor initialization syntax has been around since day 1, so it is pretty well rooted and known. The main argument for the `auto var = Type()` style would be to make things more uniform, however, when declaring a member variable, the type still has to go on the left hand side, so the argument for consistency is only partial.

Comment: Why is `#include "stdafx.h"` non-portable? Every compiler from this decade and last supports including files.

Comment: @Blindy, nothing to do with `#include` obviously. Perhaps I've expressed myself poorly. I meant that the particular file is auto-generated by VS and the `#include "stdafx.h"` line is added automatically to every `.cpp`. When you copy your project directories to another system and compiler, it will fail to find this auto-generated file.

Comment: `stdafx.h` isn't an autogenerated file, it's a physical file in your project.

Comment: @Blindly, it is a physical file that is generated by the IDE. YMMV, but I've had problems with it before, related to moving projects from VS to other systems. In this particular case, the only thing preventing this code from compiling on my Linux box is that include. So it is a thing that makes code less portable, IMHO.

Comment: It's not autogenerated, you maintain it. That's the whole idea of precompiled headers -- you tell the compiler what bunch of headers are needed for EVERY file in your project, and you tell it that by adding `#include` directives in `stdafx.h`. I'm heading to sleep so I'll drop it, but if you ever maintain even moderately large codebases you'll realize how wrong you are about advising against precompiled headers (which every compiler supports by the way).

Comment: All good points, but I'd just like to point out regarding #1 and #10, a non-virtual destructor only invokes UB when an object whose effective type is a derived type is destroyed through a pointer/reference to a base class with non-virtual destructor.  Thus the UB would technically be in the client code, which is using the class in an unsupported way.  On the other hand, there's no reason not to provide a virtual destructor in this case.  Note also the sample with `make_unique<Random>()` does not result in UB; the correct destructor is wrapped in a functor and stored in the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Humm, thanks for the comment @bcrist, I was thinking the unique_ptr would be a problem. Tomorrow I can edit this. Thanks again!

Comment: @Blindy I'm not against precompiled headers per-say, my point it that they are a compiler specific feature, so it is up to you to decide if it is worth breaking some portability in favor of them. Sometimes the gain is not worth it. In the OP, I wouldn't say it is. An again, by auto generated I was meaning the IDE provides a default with each project, but yes you may edit it at will afterwards.

Comment: @glampert Err.. actually that last part isn't quite right.  I was thinking of `shared_ptr` which does use a type-erased deleter, but `unique_ptr` uses a class template for the deleter, which defaults to `std::default_delete`.

Comment: @glampert I'd -1 you for #11, but I can't. Having `stdafx.h` does not make your code compiler dependent. I don't know where you got that idea, but it is false. Unless you can come up with a _reliable_ source that it's compiler-dependent, you're wrong. GCC supports pre compiled headers. And the best part is, _it's optional_. And because it's a _relative_ include, there's no need to tell the compiler where to find the file if you don't want to use precompiled headers. Yes, VS autogenerates it, but you still have to maintain it yourself like any other header.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is a lot of digest. I need to think about where speaking c++ in a c# accent is a bad idea, and where it is bringing good practice across. Rightly or wrongly, I seem to be developing my own coding style, and I have to think about what place non well defined types (int etc), implicit member access and the whole 'm_' thing have in that style. Thanks for pointing out the places where the c#-style syntax works but is sub-optimal (point 9,13...), that's really useful.

Comment: Regarding #13. This style is advocated by Herb Sutter and others. See [Almost Always Auto (AAA)](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/)

Comment: @ChrisDrew, I'm down for `auto` and friends whenever type inference can make code shorter clearer. In the case of statically allocated object instances, as in the OP's case, it means just more typing. Also, the argument of always using `auto` to keep a uniform syntax does not hold, since when declaring a class or struct member you still have to explicitly write the type on the left hand side.

Comment: @glampert There are many arguments for (and against). See also Herb's [GOTW 94](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) and Scott Meyer's [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/0636920033707.do) Item 5: 'Prefer auto to explicit type declarations'. I think discussion is beyond the scope of this answer but my point is, given both are recognised styles I would let it pass in a code review.

Comment: @ChrisDrew, true, perhaps that point was a bit too subjective. I'll keep that in mind next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Made some of the changes suggested by @glampert in his excellent answer. The code is [here](https://github.com/NathanLBCooper/ConsoleApplicationCpp/tree/Trunk).

I've only annotated where I've differed really, so there's very little text. Most points have been incorporated, especially 9 and 13 (those were my favorite).

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

namespace ConsoleApplicationCpp
{

    class IRandom
    {
    public:
        virtual ~IRandom() = default;
        virtual std::int32_t Next() = 0;
        virtual std::int32_t Next(std::int32_t maxValue) = 0;
        virtual std::int32_t Next(std::int32_t minValue, std::int32_t maxValue) = 0;
        virtual std::double_t NextDouble() = 0;
        virtual std::double_t NextDouble(std::double_t minValue, std::double_t maxValue) = 0;
        virtual void NextBytes(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& buffer) = 0;
    }; 

}
```

I however, do not trust the built in types and have decided to stick to `<cstdint>`, I have put in the `std::`s before these types and also decided to `std::` rather than `using namespace std`, which I'm sure is a subject that [has been discussed enough already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <random>
#include <vector>

#include "IRandom.h"

namespace ConsoleApplicationCpp
{

    class Random : public IRandom
    {
        std::mt19937 randomNumberGenerator;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<std::int32_t> byteDistribution;
    public:
        Random(std::uint_least32_t seed);
        Random() : Random(std::_Random_device()) {};
        std::int32_t Next() override;
        std::int32_t Next(std::int32_t maxValue) override;
        std::int32_t Next(std::int32_t minValue, std::int32_t maxValue) override;
        std::double_t NextDouble() override;
        std::double_t NextDouble(std::double_t minValue, std::double_t maxValue) override;
        void NextBytes(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& buffer) override;
    };

}
```

No special "_" or "m_". I've made the call to break with that sort of naming in C# (not all do) and I think it's best to break with it here. This means I will be using `this->member`. I really like using `this`, and accept I am guilty of coming to C++ and demanding it be written like C#.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>

#include "Random.h"

namespace ConsoleApplicationCpp
{
    Random::Random(std::uint_least32_t seed)
        : randomNumberGenerator(seed),
        byteDistribution(0, 256)
    {
    }

    std::int32_t Random::Next()
    {
        return this->Next(0, std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max());
    }

    std::int32_t Random::Next(std::int32_t maxValue)
    {
        return this->Next(0, maxValue);
    }

    std::int32_t Random::Next(std::int32_t minValue, std::int32_t maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue < 0 || maxValue < minValue)
        {
            throw 
                std::invalid_argument("minValue and maxValue must be non-negative. maxValue must be greater than minvalue");
        }
        std::uniform_int_distribution<std::int32_t> distribution(minValue, maxValue);
        return distribution(this->randomNumberGenerator);
    }

    std::double_t Random::NextDouble()
    {
        return this->NextDouble(0.0, 1.0);
    }

    std::double_t Random::NextDouble(std::double_t minValue, std::double_t maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue < 0.0 || maxValue < minValue)
        {
            throw
                std::invalid_argument("minValue and maxValue must be non-negative. maxValue must be greater than minvalue");
        }
        std::uniform_real_distribution<std::double_t> distribution(minValue, maxValue);
        return distribution(this->randomNumberGenerator);
    }

    void Random::NextBytes(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& buffer)
    {
        for (auto &i : buffer)
        {
            i = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(byteDistribution(this->randomNumberGenerator));
        }
    }

}
```

I've kept `"stdafx.h"` for now, mostly out of laziness, but I've stripped the `include`s out of it. I'm using it to contain some macros that cover the confusingness of `__declspec`, but I should probably split that into its own header file.

Comment: Sorry for all the updating. I put some unit tests over thing and shook out a couple of bugs and mistaken assumptions about the results of <random>. Should be good for straight copying if you need one of these, feel free (If you think it's a wise idea using someone's first console application ;D)